# best way to provide a single S3 bucket for each Cognito identity in a pool

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am evaluating options for using Cognito developer-authenticated identities and S3 storage in a platform.  Essentially, what I would like to do is create a separate S3 bucket and Cognito identity for each customer.  At this point we do not need separate Cognito identities for each user, we only use the identity to allow access to S3 storage. We will need to support several hundred customers in this scenario (so several hundred buckets with associated Cognito identities).

I have found several examples of how to do this using dedicated folders within a single S3 bucket (see [Example 1](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_examples.html#iam-policy-example-cognito) and [Example 2](http://aws-labs.com/users-signed-amazon-cognito-access-amazon-s3-folder/)).  I don't think a single bucket for all customers will be a viable solution in our case, for several reasons (one such reason is that the S3 API rate limits are apparently tied to unique buckets).

I have attempted to create access policies on the customer buckets to only allow access to specific Cognito identities, i.e.,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::CUSTOMER-BUCKET/*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "my IAM role for Cognito"
      },
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": [
            "us-east-1:customer's cognito identity"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But S3 does not recognize the cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub condition.

If I attach a similar policy to the IAM role used for the Cognito identity pool, i.e.,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectVersion",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::CUSTOMER-BUCKET/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": [
            "us-east-1:customer's cognito identity"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems to work, but obviously I would have to add a policy for each identity and bucket combination, which would run into the limitations on size of inline policies that can be added to a single role (10240 total characters).

I am scratching my head at this point trying to come up with an approach that will work.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You should definitely use a single bucket rather than one bucket per user. Do not even consider a "bucket per user" strategy.

You should look at using [IAM Policy Variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) to create one policy that applies to all users.

You can use a Cognito ID as a prefix in an S3 policy. See the **S3 Prefix** section in the [IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/iam-roles.html) documentation:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"],
      "Condition": {"StringLike": {"s3:prefix": ["${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]}}
    },
    {
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then users can access objects within their subdirectory of the same S3 bucket.

As to concerns about using a single bucket, I suggest you try it and then see whether problems actually result. Amazon S3 is highly scalable and is used by some very big web services, so it's likely to support your use-case. See: [Amazon S3 Request Rate and Performance Considerations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/request-rate-perf-considerations.html).

Comment: I am trying to use a "one bucket per company" strategy, not per user.  Each company may have hundreds or maybe thousands of users, but there will be only a single Cognito identity for each company.  I am familiar with the S3 request rate and performance considerations, which is why I'd like to spread access across multiple buckets.  I am certain that all users sharing a single bucket will be a problem at some point.  It won't take long to start bumping up against the 100 requests/sec per bucket limit.  I guess I will have to get some advice from Amazon on how to deal with this.

Comment: I'd suggest you try it and see, before doing strange things to avoid a problem you might not have. Companies like DropBox have used S3 for much more massive things (but I don't know their bucket setup).

Comment: The example in John's answer is Cognito's recommended approach to scale down access to an S3 bucket via Cognito. It allows you to avoid the role limit you mentioned. My first suggestion is to try what he said, using a single bucket. If you find that's truly blocking, you might be able to add additional attributes to the resource arrays in the role?