# How to use IAM Policy Variables and pass cognito user in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to do exactly what this other question already did

[best way to provide a single S3 bucket for each Cognito identity in a pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43633575/best-way-to-provide-a-single-s3-bucket-for-each-cognito-identity-in-a-pool)

but I don't understand how to actually write an app that would make use of IAM Policy Variables. I'm currently using Flask with flask-cognito-lib.

https://www.piwheels.org/project/flask-cognito-lib/

I have a REST endpoint that requires user to be authenticated with cognito and I can get the `sub` token easily. How do I pass it to boto3 now?

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
   region_name=_region,
   aws_access_key_id=access_key_id,
   aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

@application.route("/test")
@auth(required=True)
def test():
    return jsonify(session["claims"]["sub"])
```